# Static content does not sends by IIS

Tags: iis, response

Problem with response from IIS 7. When user do request for a page the IIS server does not return full static content: js, css, jpg, png.
But if I do refresh few times(push F5 or Ctrl-F5) the content loads fully and correctly. So what is the problem?
Server: Windows Server 2008 SP1, IIS 7.0.6001.18000
I tried a lot of things to fix it but I can't sort out the problem.
The simular problem described here http://forums.iis.net/t/1164186.aspx , but I did not found solution too.
Here is example firebug screenshot:

[image: fire bug fiddler:]

Comment: Problem resolved - increased bandwidth.(turned of router/device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increased bandwidth: replaced old router by a more faster router.